# Add newly created specific folder to .gitignore in Git

Tags: git, gitignore

I had a clean working directory and brought in a clone from a Git repo last night. 
But now my local server created and contains a stats folder which I want to ignore.

I can't seem to get Git to ignore this folder when I run a git status.

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file: app_public/views/pages/privacy.php
    new file: app_public/views/pages/terms.php
    new file: public_html/stats/ctry_usage_200908.png
    new file: public_html/stats/daily_usage_200908.png
    new file: public_html/stats/dns_cache.db
    new file: public_html/stats/hourly_usage_200908.png
    new file: public_html/stats/index.html
    new file: public_html/stats/usage.png
    new file: public_html/stats/usage_200908.html
    new file: public_html/stats/webalizer.current
    new file: public_html/stats/webalizer.hist

Changed but not updated:
    modified: .gitignore
```

I added in my .gitignore a few different lines but it still trying to add them:

```
public_html/stats
public_html/stats/**
public_html/stats/**/*
public_html/stats/*
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try `/public_html/stats/*` ?

But since the files in `git status` reported as *to be commited* that means you've already added them manually. In which case, of course, it's a bit too late to ignore. You can `git rm --cache` them (IIRC).

Comment: Wait! You have "files to be committed" — that means you've already `git add`-ed them.

Answer (score 107):

For this there are two cases

***Case 1:*** File already added to git repo.

***Case 2:*** File newly created and its status still showing as untracked file when using

```
git status
```

If you have case 1:

*STEP 1:*
Then run

```
git rm --cached filename
```

to remove it from git repo cache

if it is a directory then  use

```
git rm -r --cached  directory_name
```

*STEP 2:* If **Case 1** is over then create new file named `.gitignore` in your git repo

*STEP 3:* Use following to tell git to ignore / assume file is unchanged

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged path/to/file.txt
```

*STEP 4:* Now, check status using git status open `.gitignore` in your editor nano, vim, geany etc... any one, add the path of the file / folder to ignore. If it is a folder then user `folder_name/*` to ignore all file.

If you still do not understand read the [article git ignore file](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files) link.

Comment: I get when `fatal: Unable to mark file .idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml`
when I do `update-index`

Comment: @OlehZiniak have you figured out what should be done when one gets `fatal: Unable to mark file` error. Please help.

Comment: permission and ownership of the file which you unable to mark. in which step it shows error?

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 17):

From "git help ignore" we learn:

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it
>   is removed for the purpose of the
>   following description, but it would
>   only find a match with a directory. In
>   other words, foo/ will match a
>   directory foo and paths underneath it,
>   but will not match a regular file or a
>   symbolic link foo (this is consistent
>   with
>              the way how pathspec works in general in git).

Therefore what you need is

> public_html/stats/

Comment: That just means "public_html/stats/" will only match a directory, but not a file, but "public_html/stats" will match both the directory and a file of that name, so that's not the issue. Still a good idea though.

Comment: The man page says foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it. OP wants to ignore the folder and its contents. Aside from other issues with git add, this is how it's done.

Answer (score 6):

It's `/public_html/stats/*`.

```
$ ~/myrepo> ls public_html/stats/
bar baz foo
$ ~/myrepo> cat .gitignore 
public_html/stats/*
$ ~/myrepo> git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .gitignore
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ ~/myrepo>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm incredibly lazy. I just did a search hoping to find a shortcut to this problem but didn't get an answer so I knocked this up.

~/bin/IGNORE_ALL

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: IGNORE_ALL <commit message>                                                                                                                             
git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | cut -f2 -d' ' >> .gitignore              
git commit -m "$*" .gitignore
```

EG: IGNORE_ALL added stat ignores

This will just append all the ignore files to your .gitignore and commit. note you might want to add annotations to the file afterwards.