# Remove directories and files from git repository and add to ignore list

Tags: .net, git, osx-lion

I've got a .net solution directory (on OSX using a virtual machine) and just did a

```
$ git add .
$ git commit
```

on the whole directory.

I forgot there were a number of file and directories I didn't want added, such as my _resharper directory, and the contents of my bin folder.

So now, how do I first remove those directories and files from my local git repository without deleting them from my working copy?

Additionally, how do I add said directories to an ignore list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I untrack tracked files in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178726/how-do-i-untrack-tracked-files-in-git)

Comment: Duplicate of: [Remove directory from remote repository after adding them to .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927230/remove-directory-from-remote-repository-after-adding-them-to-gitignore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a .gitignore file in the same directory as the repo. And put

```
_resharper/
*file.cpp
```

*remember the slash after the directory name for folder names, no need asterisk

by the way, you will need to remove the folder, untrack and then put it back in if you already add and commited.

You can learn more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335302/git-gitignore-specific-folder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178726/how-do-i-untrack-tracked-files-in-git)

Comment: this will only work on untracked files, which in the OP's case, he already has.       edit: poster changed has answer accordingly

Comment: I didnt know there was already a bunch of questions on these, edited.

Comment: sorry, its a sample to show that you can ignore files AND folders. Add an edit

Answer (score 1):

```
git reflog
git reset @HEAD{x} # x depends on what you see in reflog 
#edit .gitignore
#add line in gitignore 
#_resharper/
```

Comment: thanks ralu. If I add bin/ to the ignore file, will it ignore it even though the bin folder isn't in the working dir?

Comment: Yes I usually edit .gitignore in .git folder and I am using GitExtensions on windows and gitx on linux to visualise what is going on before staging. You might try whit gitx on osx.