# how to ignore a directory and its sub-directories in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore public folder and its inside folders and file in git

```
public/app
public/dist/file.html
public/dist/bower_components/
public/dist/fonts/
public/dist/scripts/
```

i want to ignore all of them and their inside files 
i followed this link 
[Add newly created specific folder to .gitignore in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335302/add-newly-created-specific-folder-to-gitignore-in-git)

I am doing it like this in .gitignore file

```
public/app/*
public/dist//*
public/dist/bower_components/*
public/dist/fonts/*
public/dist/scripts/
```

but its not working ,i can stil see these files on `git status`

Comment: please share the output of `git status`, also mention whether you have tried `git rm` as suggested in the link in your post

Answer (score 1):

Ignore `/public/` (leading and trailing slashes, no asterisk).

Comment: Or, better yet, `/public/`, to avoid unintentionally also ignoring `some/path/to/public/`...

Comment: Agree. Updated. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

First verify `git status` if you have already add this folders. If you was add, try to remove them `git rm -r --cached directory`.

Next put only `public/*` in .gitignore to ignore all file in public's folder.